# How to change views clicking by button?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have registration form with 3 steps. The view of form should be changed on the another view clicking by button Next.

How to realize that in Angular 2? I tried to use  routing, but it replace me whole page.

Comment: What do you mean by "replace me whole page"? Thats the goal of routing. Expose another view in the browser.

Comment: Could you post some code? How is your form built? How your routing is defined? What action is bind to the `next` button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am creating that functionality right now for my application and the solution I've chosen is using tabs. Here you have a basic example (please note that the tab component was created by me, but you could use the ones from [prime-ng](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tabview)). The point is that the next button just makes visible the next tab, hiding the current one. If you are using model driven forms you can easily navigate back and forward keeping the form field values:

```
<tabs>
    <tab title="Patient Information">
        <patient-data (onValid)="setPatientValid($event)"></patient-data>
    </tab>
    <tab title="Tab 2" [activable]="isPatientInformationValid()"></tab>
</tabs>
```

Here you have my tabs implementation (actually it is very simple):

Tabs component (the tabs container):

```
import { Component, Input, ContentChildren, QueryList, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TabComponent } from './tab.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'tabs',
    template: `
<div class="tabs-container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [class.active]="tab.active" [class.disabled]="!tab.activable" (click)="selectTab(tab)"><a>{{tab.title}}</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ng-content> </ng-content>
</div>`
})
export class TabsComponent implements AfterContentInit {

    @ContentChildren(TabComponent) tabs: QueryList<TabComponent>

    constructor() { }

    selectTab(tab: TabComponent) {
        if (tab.activable) {
            this.tabs.forEach(tab => tab.active = false);
            tab.active = true;
        }
    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        let activeTabs = this.tabs.filter((tab) => tab.active);
        // if there is no active tab set, activate the first
        if (activeTabs.length === 0) {
            this.selectTab(this.tabs.first);
        } else if (activeTabs.length > 1) {
            this.selectTab(activeTabs[0]);
        }
    }

}
```

And the Tab component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TabsComponent } from './tabs.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'tab',
    template: `
<div *ngIf="active">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>`
})
export class TabComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() title: string;
    active: boolean=true;
    @Input() activable: boolean=true;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, then I can create object with tabs and status them. What kind of this object should be? `public tabs: <type> {}`

Comment: I've updated the answer showing how to create a basic implementation

Answer (score 1):

You could use conditional classes to hide/show form sections depending on a variable in your component.

HTML:

```
<div [class.hidden]="selectedSection != 1">
    Form content 1
</div>

<div [class.hidden]="selectedSection != 2">
    Form content 2
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

and in your component:

```
selectedSection: number = 1;
```

then just change that variable when you want to change form section.

You could then add animations to these sections if you wanted.
Depends how you want it to appear visually really.

Comment: Thank you, how to add animation to this?

Comment: You could either use vanilla CSS transitions or Angular animations.

You won't be able to do CSS transitions using { display: none; } but you could animate the height/width/opacity etc of each form section instead.

Alternatively for anguar animations, check this link out: https://angular.io/guide/animations

Comment: Angular discourages using hidden, it is cleaner using just `*ngIf` to render or not an element